# automatically comparison of all possible pairs

Tags: linux, bash

I have a txt file in which columns are divided by ",". My input file is similar to this:

```
ID,pKi,cod,name
4a,6,34,
4b,7,54,yui
4c,8,64,ter
```

I would like to obtained all possible pairs considering the ID column and for each pair having the related information reported in the other columns.

Expected output

```
ID1,ID2,pk1,pk2,cod1,cod2,name1,name2
4a,4b,6,7,34,54,,yui
4a,4c,6,8,34,64,,ter
4b,4c,7,8,54,64,yiu,ter
```

As reported, I would only a unique pair, without considering othe rpossible combination of the same ID (ex. 4b,4a or 4c,4a or 4c,4b). Moreover my real input file have more rows and sometimes could has less and sometimes more columns, but I would like a script that works independently by the number of columns and rows.

Could someone help me with this challange? I am not very expert in script and I would need this script for work matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using a tool that can process csv files in a SQL-like manner, e.g. [csvjoin](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvjoin.html) (you need an "outer join"). There are other, similar tools, so pick one.

Comment: How big (roughly) is the file, compared to the amount of memory you have on the computer?

Comment: The infut file in this case si not too big. It has about 20 rows. Generally could be also more bigger but I don-t have memory problems.